# Looking for derivation of "axioms" for the real numbers from ZFC / Peano Axioms (1978?)

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

I am looking for a derivation of the "axioms" for the real numbers starting from scratch with ZFC / Peano Axioms. I don't recall the title or author, but the publication date may have been around 1978.

**EDIT:** Any derivation would do. I had just seen a passing reference to such a work some time ago, one that was published in 1978. I want to use my DC Proof software to start from Peano's Axioms and use set theory to formally construct R, then prove the field axioms, etc. I know this is a huge project. I tried several years ago, but got bogged on even elementary proofs of the properties of Dedekind cuts. I am thinking of giving it another try, with some professional help this time.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific text, or would you be happy with any derivation of the basic principles of $\mathbb{R}$ from ZFC? (PA can't possibly do the job - how can you even talk about arbitrary reals in the language of arithmetic?)

Comment: I had heard about a specific publication in 1978 (?). Any derivation would do, I suppose. I'm OK with assuming the natural numbers to start. In fact, I would probably skip their construction using ZFC. I want to go from Peano's Axiom and use set theory to construct R, then prove that field axioms, etc. using my DC Proof system. I tried several years ago, but got bogged on elementary proofs of the properties of Dedekind cuts. I got help here and other forums but couldn't translate suggestions into formal proof. Just not that clever.

Comment: I think you should look at Dedekind's original essay on cuts. It's quite nice, and you'll wind up paralleling his steps just using the machinery of ZFC.

Comment: For some texbooks primarily devoted to this, see my answer to [Materials for teaching the axioms of the real numbers to high school students](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1083584/materials-for-teaching-the-axioms-of-the-real-numbers-to-high-school-students).

Answer (score 2):

Halmos ,P ,Naive set theory then Landau ,Foundations of Analysis will get the whole construction.
 Mendelson ,Elliot ,Number Systems and the Foundations of Analysis (Dover) has it all except for the derivation of the Piano axioms from set theory (see Halmos for this ) and more -this is an excellent book . Also Rudin -Principles of Mathematical Analysis has most of the Dedekind Cut construction except that he left out the proofs for the multiplication of reals ;Mendelson has this In the appendix -it is easy to overlook this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you're asking for any reference that provides this or a specific one. If I recall correctly, Terry Tao's analysis book at least does something close to this. He doesn't really construct the natural numbers in ZFC, but he builds the real numbers assuming the natural numbers exist satisfying the Peano axioms. It's also a very good intro to analysis.

Comment: Does he use Dedekind cuts or Cauchy sequences to derive the field axioms, etc. for the reals?

Comment: He uses Cauchy sequences. And then I think in the second volume he goes on to talk more generally about other metric spaces.